Using fees in WooCommerce as way to apply Digital Wallet discounted value not assuming total order value
So the question here is actually simple, but the solution maybe simple but I've searched a lot and no answer found so far.
In the code bellow I have it almost working as I need. I say almost because this is what's happening to me right now, here's the example scenario:

I have an order that costs me 22.05 in products and 9.66 in shipping, which gives me a total of 31.71
I have in my digital wallet 500, so that's more than enough to apply here
Whenever I apply (yes, I've tested with a lot different scenarios and even forced the wallet_amount to a higher value), I ALWAYS get the fee shown as, in this specific example, -31.70 instead of -30.71
Plus, although I have the total amount for the order showing as 0 as it should, I have taxes being shown to customer and there's saying "including 0.01 TAX", which makes no sense at all

And here's the code in question:
// Wallet value applied to cart including shipping cost
function hpb2b_handle_wallet_usage() {
    if (isset($_POST['use_wallet'])) {
        $use_wallet = $_POST['use_wallet'] === 'yes';
        
        if ($use_wallet) {
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            $balance = get_user_meta($user_id, '_wallet_balance', true) ?: 0;
            
            WC()->session->set('use_wallet', true);
            $total_cart_and_shipping = WC()->cart->total;  // This should include shipping and taxes
            $total_to_deduct = min($balance, $total_cart_and_shipping);
            // Round up to the nearest cent before setting it
            $total_to_deduct = ceil($total_to_deduct * 100) / 100;  // Rounding up to nearest cent
            WC()->session->set('wallet_amount', $total_to_deduct);
        } else {
            WC()->session->set('use_wallet', false);
            WC()->session->set('wallet_amount', 0);
        }
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_apply_wallet_discount', 'hpb2b_handle_wallet_usage');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_apply_wallet_discount', 'hpb2b_handle_wallet_usage');

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'apply_wallet_discount_to_cart_and_shipping', 20);
function apply_wallet_discount_to_cart_and_shipping($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if (WC()->session->get('use_wallet')) {
        $discount_amount = WC()->session->get('wallet_amount');
        if ($discount_amount > 0) {
            // Apply the rounded discount to the cart
            $cart->add_fee(__('Carteira Digital', 'hpb2b-custom'), -$discount_amount, false);
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'update_wallet_balance_after_purchase', 10, 1);
function update_wallet_balance_after_purchase($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    $balance = get_user_meta($user_id, '_wallet_balance', true) ?: 0;
    
    if (WC()->session->get('use_wallet')) {
        $discount_amount = WC()->session->get('wallet_amount');
        update_user_meta($user_id, '_wallet_balance', max(0, $balance - $discount_amount));
        
        // Reset session variables
        WC()->session->set('use_wallet', false);
        WC()->session->set('wallet_amount', 0);
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_calculated_total', 'adjust_final_total_based_on_wallet', 10, 2);
function adjust_final_total_based_on_wallet($total, $cart) {
    if (WC()->session->get('use_wallet')) {
        $wallet_amount = WC()->session->get('wallet_amount');
        $cart_total = $cart->cart_contents_total + $cart->shipping_total + $cart->get_cart_contents_tax() + $cart->get_shipping_tax();

        if ($wallet_amount >= $cart_total) {
            // Force the total to zero if the wallet covers it
            return 0;
        } else {
            // Apply the wallet amount and adjust the total accordingly
            return max(0, $cart_total - $wallet_amount);
        }
    }

    return $total;
}


We don't do "SOLVED" in the title here. If you found your own answer, you should either post it and accept it, or delete the question

Inside menu WooCommerce > Settings > Tax we have this: Rounding Round tax at subtotal level, instead of rounding per line
Checked this option and all is good now!
